# rsync command on target server is located in different directory than on source server. How to use rsync?

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, sunos

I want to copy files from one server (**server A**) to another (**server B**) using rsync (yes, only rsync).

When using rsync on **server A** it returns:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/rsync: No such file or directory
```

Typing in rsync on **server A** and **server B** both show up information about rsync so it is available. But I discovered that on **server A** the rsync command is located in `/usr/local/bin/rsync`, while on **server B** it is located in `/usr/bin/rsync`.

How do I tell rsync that on **server A** rsync is located in path `/usr/bin/rsync`?

**Server A** runs on SunOS and **server B** runs on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the `--rsync-path` option:

```
rsync --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync SRC... DEST
```

See [`man rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for the details.

Comment: I don't think it matters as long as $PATH is set correctly.

Comment: @ventsyv: well, you are right, but I think this is out of scope for this question. This is just my opinion, of course.

Comment: Thanks Andrea, that did it